# Can't create new Flutter Provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

Hi I am trying to add a new Provider on the root level of my App. However, the create function of the new Provider (In this case more easily represented by the Provider of type int) doens't get called as I can see in my Console.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<SingleChildWidget> providers = [
    Provider<DynamicLinkService>(
      create: (context) {
        print("Dynamic Link Service Provider gets built");
        return DynamicLinkService();
      },
    ),
    Provider<int>(create: (context) {
      print("Int Provider gets built");
      return 1;
    }),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: providers,
      builder: (ctx, _) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: themeData(context),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
            return getPageRoute(settings);
          },
          home: StartUpView(),
          navigatorKey: locator<NavigationService>().navigatorKey,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Console Output:

```
Dynamic Link Service Provider gets built
```

Comment: Try defining them directly within the build function. In your example they are instantiated when `MyApp` is created, not when the `build` function is called.

Comment: @StefanGaller Thank you for your answer, I just tried it. Unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: Providers are instantiated lazily by default. If you want them to be created right away try using `lazy: false`